# Android Eclipse: Archive for required library: cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

I am trying to integrate facebook to my android app. I followed [facebook tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/) and imported facebook-android-3.14 into Eclipse. However, I got problems with some hidden files, I think. I did google a lot but still cannot figure it out.

It seems that I have to remove the hidden files like '._bolts.jar' from Android Private Library (libs folder) but I could not see it even when I turn on viewing hidden files on  Mac. Any one have ideas? Thanks in advanced.

```
Archive for required library: '/Volumes/BOTH/Win/Working/facebook-android-sdk-3.14/AudienceNetwork/samples/AdUnitsSample/libs/._AudienceNetwork.jar' in project 'AdUnitsSample' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file   AdUnitsSample       Build path  Build Path Problem

Archive for required library: '/Volumes/BOTH/Win/Working/facebook-android-sdk-3.14/AudienceNetwork/samples/NativeAdSample/libs/._AudienceNetwork.jar' in project 'NativeAdSample' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file NativeAdSample      Build path  Build Path Problem

Archive for required library: '/Volumes/BOTH/Win/Working/facebook-android-sdk-3.14/facebook/libs/._bolts.jar' in project 'FacebookSDK' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file    FacebookSDK     Build path  Build Path Problem
```

Comment: From here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526072/archive-for-required-library-could-not-be-read-or-is-not-a-valid-zip-file

It's an eclipse bug. Try restarting eclipse.

Comment: Thank Shivam, I already tried it before posting error on here. The problem is that I cannot delete hidden files in my Android Private Library. I also tried to delete them from libs folder but I couldn't see them, of course I turned on view hidden files on my lap (Mac).

Comment: A bit late but for anyone who has the same problem. I also use Window (boot camp) and I can now delete those files on Window.