# Eclipse Kepler cannot read ant.readme file

Tags: java

After installing Eclipse Kepler, I am unable to run my projects from Eclipse. I received the following errors:

> "Archive for required library:
>   'external/swixml/Dev/bololib/ant.readme' in project 'Bolo UI' cannot
>   be read or is not a valid ZIP file"

I have no problems running my projects using Eclipse Helios.

Thanks,

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's trying to read a zip. Did you read the error message?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have tried restarting, closing/opening the project and all, but this seems to be a bug in Eclipse. It has been documented here:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=375249

EDIT: Also found a SO thread

[archive for required library could not be read or is not a valid ZIP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526072/archive-for-required-library-could-not-be-read-or-is-not-a-valid-zip-file)