# Unable to resolve Eclipse "Archive for required library..." issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, build

I need help with resolving this very common Eclipse error.

**Background**: I am working on an android project with Eclipse(juno) ADT  on Ubuntu 14.10 and everything was fine till I decided to work with websockets in the code, for which I included json-org.jar and WebSocket.jar, downloaded from the [github project here](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client/tree/master/libs).

**Problem**:
I now get the "Archive for required library:  cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file" error for both these JARs.

I've spent countless hours trying to fix this build issue. So far, I've done the following:

- Add the JARs to the buildpath. Removed and Added them again.
- Downloaded the JARs again and replaced the previous files.
- Restart Eclipse.
- Close and Open the concerned project.
- Cleaned and Build the specific project.
- Cleaned the Eclipse cache by executing ./eclipse -clean from the terminal.
- Lowered my java compiler from 1.7 to 1.5
- Created a separate Android Workspace and imported the project into the new one.
- Didn't do Maven cleaning stuff since I don't use Maven.

So far, everything I've looked up and tried has failed. I have referred to the following related questions:

- [Compiler error “archive for required library could not be read” - Spring Tool Suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857985/compiler-error-archive-for-required-library-could-not-be-read-spring-tool-su)
- [archive for required library could not be read or is not a valid ZIP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526072/archive-for-required-library-could-not-be-read-or-is-not-a-valid-zip-file)

Here's a screenshot of what the project build looks like:

[image]

Can someone please help me fix this! I really need help with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now fixed the issue.

I think there was a duplication conflict between some of the JARs included in the project. Eliminating WebSocket.jar, json-org.jar and java-websocket-1.3.0.jar resolved the build issue and the code didn't really need these JAR dependencies anyways.