# Error after trying to add library

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio

In android studio i'm trying to add a mysql connector library for my app. after pasting the jar into the lib folder and ensuring that it was listed to compile in build.gradle. I click run app and get this error before it even asks for an emulator to run on:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     'E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with
> >     non-zero exit value 1

If I delete the jar I pasted in then this error disappears.

my dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile files('libs/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar')
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio unable to resolve error ':app:preDexDebug'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28933701/android-studio-unable-to-resolve-error-apppredexdebug)

Comment: Have you looked at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung I've done everything in that post, i added the dependencies code to my question. Thought it might be the first line so i tried removing the compile filetree then tried removing the compile files instead both times I get the same error

Answer (score 1):

Current Android dex compiler cannot recognize mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar or later because they are compiled for Java1.8.

see: [android JDBC mysql java connector app:preDexDebug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34264548/4506703)