# eclipse : play-service.pom cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, google-play-services

Is any suggest. How  to resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: As stated in this related SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19526180/5995040), this is an eclipse bug. Also try using Android Studio as it is the [official IDE](https://youtu.be/jNax9GzFheQ) for android and you might want to check the [migrate to Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html) for this. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After imported play-service-gcm.class everything  work fine.